# Bootstrap 4 issue with keeping cols in a row on iphone

Tags: css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I am a bit puzzled. How can I get this timer here to stay in 1 line on iPhone? On iPhone the "seconds" goes to the next line and looks pretty bad => https://ibb.co/k2iCfo

Bootstrap code:

```html
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div id = "timer_frame" class="col-md-12"> 
      <div class="row justify-content-md-center d-flex">
        <div class="col text-center col_bg">
          <span class="days display-4 timer_font_color"></span>
          <span class="d-block timer_font_color">Days</span>
        </div>

        <div class="col text-center timer_font_color col_bg">
          <span class="hours display-4 timer_font_color"></span>
          <span class="d-block timer_font_color">Hours</span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col text-center timer_font_color col_bg">
          <span class="minutes display-4"></span>
          <span class="d-block timer_font_color">Minutes</span>
        </div>

        <div class="col text-center timer_font_color col_bg">
          <span class="seconds display-4"></span>
          <span class="d-block timer_font_color">Seconds</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Link => https://webmoosh.com/login

And here is the page raw => http://webmoosh.com/broadcast.html

Thanks

Comment: try col-xs-3 instead of col

Comment: use `col-xs-3` for mobile , `col-sm-3` for tablets, `col-md-3` for laptops

Answer (score 2):

Replacing `display-4` with `display-md-4` and adding a `display-sm-3` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add classes to the parent `.row`

```
<div class="row justify-content-md-center d-flex row  flex-nowrap flex-sm-wrap">
    <div class="col text-center col_bg">
      <span class="days display-4 timer_font_color">741</span>
      <span class="d-block timer_font_color">Days</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col text-center timer_font_color col_bg">
      <span class="hours display-4 timer_font_color">14</span>
      <span class="d-block timer_font_color">Hours</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col text-center timer_font_color col_bg">
      <span class="minutes display-4">52</span>
      <span class="d-block timer_font_color">Minutes</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col text-center timer_font_color col_bg">
      <span class="seconds display-4">21</span>
      <span class="d-block timer_font_color">Seconds</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and reduce the `font-size` of `display-4`

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
      .display-4 {
         font-size: 2.0rem;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the size of the font a little smaller in display-4 class.  For example:

```
.display-4 {
   font-size: 2.5rem;
   font-weight: 300;
   line-height: 1.2;
}
```

And here is an image of the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

here is the bootstrap code for it this will work:

xs (for phones - screens less than 768px wide)

sm (for tablets - screens equal to or greater than 768px wide)

md (for small laptops - screens equal to or greater than 992px wide)

lg (for laptops and desktops - screens equal to or greater than 1200px wide)

```
<div class="container-fluid img-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" >days code goes here </div>
    <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" >hours code goes here</div>
    <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" >minutes code goes here</div>
    <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" >seconds code goes here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The OP has specified they are using Bootstrap 4, which no longer supports the `-xs` suffix in column sizing.  `img-responsive` is also now `img-fluid` though it's unclear to me why that is in your example code.

Comment: @RobertC i hav made the required changes.

Answer (score 0):

With "row" class use "flex-nowrap" and on "col_bg" class remove margin and use padding instead. last div is breaking because row have property flex-wrap:wrap. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `col` classes to `col-xs-3` and your `display-4` classes to `display-xs-3`

```
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div id = "timer_frame" class="col-md-12"> 
      <div class="row justify-content-md-center d-flex">
        <div class="col-xs-3 text-center col_bg">
          <span class="days display-xs-3 timer_font_color"></span>
          <span class="d-block timer_font_color">Days</span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-3 text-center timer_font_color col_bg">
          <span class="hours display-xs-3 timer_font_color"></span>
          <span class="d-block timer_font_color">Hours</span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-3 text-center timer_font_color col_bg">
          <span class="minutes display-xs-3"></span>
          <span class="d-block timer_font_color">Minutes</span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-3 text-center timer_font_color col_bg">
          <span class="seconds display-xs-3"></span>
          <span class="d-block timer_font_color">Seconds</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Change also this rule to your `col_bg` class to have a better centering of the tiles

```
.col_bg{
    margin: 3px;
}
```

Comment: The `-xs` suffix was removed in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: @RobertC Thanks! I didn't know that. You gave me work for the afternoon. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would approach your structure slightly differently and make use of the `no-gutters` class to remove the padding between each column.  Once you remove that you can play with the margin values without inadvertently breaking the layout at certain breakpoints.

```js
  $(function() {
    var timezone = "Atlantic/Madeira",
        offer_open_date_time = "2020-06-03 04:30",
        $clock = $('.days');

    $clock.on('update.countdown', function(event) {
      $(".days").text(event.strftime("%-D"));
      $(".hours").text(event.strftime("%-H"));
      $(".minutes").text(event.strftime("%-M"));
      $(".seconds").text(event.strftime("%-S"));
    });
        
    updateCountdown();
        
    function updateCountdown() {
      var date = moment.tz("2020-06-03 04:30", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm", timezone);
      $clock.countdown(date.toDate());
    }
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://webmoosh.com/components/js/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://webmoosh.com/components/js/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://webmoosh.com/components/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://webmoosh.com/components/js/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row no-gutters text-center" id="timer_frame">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="bg-dark text-secondary rounded mr-1">
        <span class="days display-4 display-md-3 d-block">12</span>
        <span class="d-block timer_font_color">Days</span>
      </div>
    </div>
        
    <div class="col">
      <div class="bg-dark text-secondary rounded mr-1">
        <span class="hours display-4 display-md-3 d-block">24</span>
        <span class="d-block timer_font_color">Hours</span>
      </div>
    </div>
        
    <div class="col">
      <div class="bg-dark text-secondary rounded mr-1">
      <span class="minutes display-4 display-md-3 d-block">60</span>
      <span class="d-block timer_font_color">Minutes</span>
      </div>
    </div>
        
    <div class="col">
      <div class="bg-dark text-secondary rounded">
        <span class="seconds display-4 display-md-3 d-block">60</span>
        <span class="d-block timer_font_color">Seconds</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This displays in a single line on my iPhone 6S both in horizontal and portrait mode.  Overall the structure isn't terribly different from your own... I've removed an additional `row` and tied the `#timer_frame` declaration to the `row no-gutters text-center` wrapper.  Most of the rest of the changes are in some responsive sizing for `display-*` and pushing some of your custom CSS out in favor of Bootstrap's built in utility classes (like `rounded` or `m*-*` for pushing margins).

Feel free to ignore the `bg-dark text-secondary` bit; I didn't want to bother writing custom CSS to apply coloring for the sample code :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using media queries, works well.

```html
@media (min-width: 576px) 
      {  
        span.days, span.hours, span.minutes, span.seconds
          {
            font-size: 30px;
          }
      }
   @media (min-width: 768px)
      {  
        span.days, span.hours, span.minutes, span.seconds 
          {
            font-size: 50px;
          }
      }

    @media (min-width: 992px)
      {  
        span.days, span.hours, span.minutes, span.seconds 
          {
            font-size: 50px;
          }
      }

     @media (min-width: 1200px)
      {  
        span.days, span.hours, span.minutes, span.seconds 
          {
            font-size: 50px;
          }
      }
```